# how to format array from string in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I want if the first number in the string is 2 the output will be 2 array. How to explode as each array from string.

My code

```
<?php

$str = "2,2;2;,1;1;,07-09-2016;07-09-2016;,08-09-2016;10-09-2016;,1;3;,100.00;450.00;";


$data = explode(',',$str); 
$out = array();
for($i=1;$i < count($data)-1;$i++){

   $out[]= explode(';',$data[$i]);

}

$i = $out[0][0];


foreach ($out as $key => $value) {


for($a=0;$a < $i; $a++){

    echo $value[$a]. "<br/>";
}

}

?>
```

I get the result **221107-09-201607-09-201608-09-201610-09-201613**
But I want this format

```
<?php

$str = "2,2;2;,1;1;,07-09-2016;07-09-2016;,08-09-2016;10-09-2016;,1;3;,100.00;450.00;";

//format will be split by semicomma ;
$arr1 = Array('2','1','07-09-2016','08-09-2016','1','100.00');
$arr2 = Array('2','1','07-09-2016','10-09-2016','3','450.00');

?>
```

Comment: Use `explode()` and `array_map()`...? https://eval.in/637129

Comment: i use like this but it not ok $data = explode(',',$str); 
$out = array();
for($i=1;$i < count($data)-1;$i++){
 
 $out[]= explode(';',$data[$i]);
 
}

$i = $out[0][0];


foreach ($out as $key => $value) {
  
 
 for($a=0;$a < $i; $a++){
 
  echo $value[$a];
 }
  
}

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: can you help explain how you end up at the result you want? For example, why is the last element `450.00` in `arr2` and not in `arr1`?

Comment: @Scott I combine two array as string and i want the format out as two arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The php function `array_column` will come in handy here. Here is short code example that should output what you are looking for.

```
<?php
//Your original input
$str =     "2,2;2;,1;1;,07-09-2016;07-09-2016;,08-09-2016;10-09-2016;,1;3;,100.00;450.00";

//explode the array into its sub-arrays
$arrs = explode(",", $str);

//remove the first element that sets how many elements are in each array
$numArrs = array_shift($arrs);

//convert strings into those wanted sub-arrays
array_walk($arrs, function(&$val, $key) {  $val = explode(';',$val); });

//make the answer we need
$ans = array();
for($i=0; $i<$numArrs; $i++) {
    //array_column does all the work that we want, making life easy
    $ans[] = array_column($arrs, $i);
}

var_dump($ans);
```

This process does assume the string is properly formatted for what we are looking for - it will fail horribly if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `explode()` function! It's really cool.
Here's how I would solve this problem. You will end up with a 2d array with my code. You can access `$arr1` with `$fourthStep[0]` and $arr2 with `$fourthStep[1]` etc...

```
<?php
 $str = "2,2;2;,1;1;,07-09-2016;07-09-2016;,08-09-2016;10-09-2016;,1;3;,100.00;450.00;";
 $fourthStep = array();

 //First, let's split that string up into something a little more.. readable.
 $firstStep = explode(",",$str);
 //$firstStep[0] contains our count for the total array count.
 foreach($firstStep as $secondStep){ //Our second step is to loop through the newly created array which splits each section of your array
     if ($secondStep != $firstStep[0]){ //skip the first part, as that is only telling us of array count
         $thirdStep = explode(";",$secondStep); //third step is to get each data part of each section. The count of this array should be 'firstStep[0]-1'       
         for($i = 0; $i<$firstStep[0]; $i++){
             //Now we want to assign the values into a 2D array
            $fourthStep[$i][count($fourthStep[$i])] = $thirdStep[$i];
         }


     }
 }

 var_dump($fourthStep);
 ?>
```

Result:
`array(2) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(10) "07-09-2016" [3]=> string(10) "08-09-2016" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(6) "100.00" } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(10) "07-09-2016" [3]=> string(10) "10-09-2016" [4]=> string(1) "3" [5]=> string(6) "450.00" } }`

Just for a further note, you don't need the '2' in the first part of your string to work out how many arrays to split it into, as they use 2 different seperators you can work it out quite easily. Save like 8 bits of space or somethin'